# Android - Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer

Tags: android, apache-httpclient-4.x, fileoutputstream

I have this piece of code that takes the server response and writes it into a file.

The file contains json data. I write response into file in order to scan json sequentially and to avoid to load big json data in a List!

I Think exception is thrown in this method but I'm not sure!

```
public File getData(final String url) throws URISyntaxException, AuthenticationException, IOException, ClientProtocolException, HttpResponseException {
    final HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(new URI(url));

    final UsernamePasswordCredentials creds = new UsernamePasswordCredentials(username, password);
    getRequest.addHeader(new BasicScheme().authenticate(creds, getRequest));
    getRequest.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    final ResponseHandler<byte[]> responseHandler = new ByteArrayResponseHandler();
    final byte[] responseBody = mClient.execute(getRequest, responseHandler);

    final File output = new File(FileConfig.TEMP_PATH + System.currentTimeMillis()+".json");
    final FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(output.getPath()); 

    fos.write(responseBody);
    fos.close();
    return output;
}
```

But I've noticed that recently (I don't know why) I get this exception:

```
01-22 07:45:51.809: E/System(9055): Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer
01-22 07:45:51.833: E/System(9055): java.io.IOException: close failed: EIO (I/O error)
01-22 07:45:51.833: E/System(9055):     at libcore.io.IoUtils.close(IoUtils.java:41)
01-22 07:45:51.833: E/System(9055):     at java.io.FileInputStream.close(FileInputStream.java:121)
01-22 07:45:51.833: E/System(9055):     at java.io.FileInputStream.finalize(FileInputStream.java:142)
01-22 07:45:51.833: E/System(9055):     at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:185)
01-22 07:45:51.833: E/System(9055):     at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:168)
01-22 07:45:51.833: E/System(9055):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
01-22 07:45:51.833: E/System(9055): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: close failed: EIO (I/O error)
01-22 07:45:51.833: E/System(9055):     at libcore.io.Posix.close(Native Method)
01-22 07:45:51.833: E/System(9055):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.close(BlockGuardOs.java:75)
01-22 07:45:51.833: E/System(9055):     at libcore.io.IoUtils.close(IoUtils.java:38)
01-22 07:45:51.833: E/System(9055):     ... 5 more
01-22 07:45:51.833: E/System(9055): Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer
01-22 07:45:51.841: E/System(9055): java.io.IOException: close failed: EIO (I/O error)
01-22 07:45:51.841: E/System(9055):     at libcore.io.IoUtils.close(IoUtils.java:41)
01-22 07:45:51.841: E/System(9055):     at java.io.FileInputStream.close(FileInputStream.java:121)
01-22 07:45:51.841: E/System(9055):     at java.io.FileInputStream.finalize(FileInputStream.java:142)
01-22 07:45:51.841: E/System(9055):     at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:185)
01-22 07:45:51.841: E/System(9055):     at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:168)
01-22 07:45:51.841: E/System(9055):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
01-22 07:45:51.841: E/System(9055): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: close failed: EIO (I/O error)
01-22 07:45:51.841: E/System(9055):     at libcore.io.Posix.close(Native Method)
01-22 07:45:51.841: E/System(9055):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.close(BlockGuardOs.java:75)
01-22 07:45:51.841: E/System(9055):     at libcore.io.IoUtils.close(IoUtils.java:38)
01-22 07:45:51.841: E/System(9055):     ... 5 more
```

Everything seems to work, but I'm perplexed about this exception.

The targetSdk ok my app is 13.

Thanks for any comment / response!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

update your code some thing like this.

```
 public File getData(final String url) throws URISyntaxException, AuthenticationException, IOException, ClientProtocolException, HttpResponseException {
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    File output = null;

    final HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(new URI(url));

    final UsernamePasswordCredentials creds = new UsernamePasswordCredentials(
            username, password);
    getRequest.addHeader(new BasicScheme().authenticate(creds, getRequest));
    getRequest.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    final ResponseHandler<byte[]> responseHandler = new ByteArrayResponseHandler();
    final byte[] responseBody = mClient
            .execute(getRequest, responseHandler);

    try {
        output = new File(FileConfig.TEMP_PATH + System.currentTimeMillis()
                + ".json");
        fos = new FileOutputStream(output.getPath());

        fos.write(responseBody);

        fos.flush();
        fos.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

    } catch (IOException e) {

    } catch (Exception e) {

    } finally {
        if (fos != null) {
            fos = null;
        }
    }
    return output;
 }
```

Because when your trying to fos.wrire() or fos.close() it may through IOException and when your calling new FileOutputStream(output.getPath()); it may through FileNotFoundException.

Comment: I have added something like your code.. but even the catch (Exception e) is called.. so I think exception is not raised here.. but how can I know where exception is raised? the log contains no information about my classes / packages.. mah...

Comment: I think I've solved.. not the piece of code I've posted.. but I don't close JsonParser object before delete file on which is attached.. Thank you very much for your response!!